# Drupal node access for anonymous users

Tags: drupal, authentication

I've never used Drupal before so this may be something that can easily be remedied, and that would be awesome.

My problem is that a block, containing node information can't be viewed by anonymous users (unregisterd/not logged in), gives a "You are not authorized to access this content." message, but shows up for logged in users. The nodes that the block contains are events, so the block shows events for the next week.

I've checked the users access settings but can't find anything that could possibly remedy this.

I'm using drupal core 6.26, Event 6.x-2.x-dev, Event views 6.x-2.4

If anyone has any information, or solutions, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the Event module to provide an "event" node type, then using Event Views to make them available to Views, which then generates a block. Permissions are set up so that only "authenticated user" and higher-privileged users can view event nodes.

If so, the modules are doing exactly what they are supposed to do. If an "anonymous user" is not allowed to view "event" content, then they will not be able to access any part of that content until they log in.

For finer control, for instance to show the names and dates of upcoming events but not their descriptions to anonymous users, I suspect you would need to abandon the event module. That module was born in an era when creating a new node type required installing a separate module. Since you are on Drupal 6, you can use the [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) modules to set up a new content type, then migrate the content over with Date Tools (which is bundled with the Date module). Then, you can use Content Permissions (bundled with CCK) to allow some fields, like the event date, to be visible to anonymous users, while hiding the rest.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. I'll look into what you suggested.